# Storing a particular parameter's value for each time a function is being run within another function

Tags: r, function, ode

I have written a function that is being run by another function of an R package many times, but I wish to access few of the inner parameter's of my function for each time the function is being used, but it's impossible to do so when my function is being used by an R package's function.

```
library(pracma)


model <- function(t,x,params){

  y0 <- x[1]
  y1 <- x[2]
  y2 <- x[3]
  y3 <- x[4]

  ry <- params[1]
  mu <- params[2]
  d0 <- params[3]
  ay <- params[4]
  d1 <- params[5]
  by <- params[6]
  d2 <- params[7]
  cy <- params[8]
  d3 <- params[9]



  m <- rep(0,4)
  m[1] = ((ry*(1-mu)) - d0) * y0 #####I want to store the value of y0
  m[2] = (ay * y0) - (d1 * y1) #######and y1
  m[3] = (by * y1) - (d2 * y2) #######and y2
  m[4] = (cy * y2) - (d3 * y3) #######and y3, for each time ode23 calls my function

  return(m)

}

ay = 1.6 / 100
d1 = 0.008
by = 10 / 750
d2 = 0.05
cy = 100
d3 = 1

y_0 = 250000
y_1 = (ay*y_0) / d1
y_2 = (by*y_1) / d2
y_3 = (cy*y_2) / d3



x <- ode23(model, y0 = c(y0=y_0, y1=y_1, y2=y_2, y3=y_3), t0=0,tf=400,
 params = c(0.008,4*10^-8,0.003,1.6/100,0.008,10/750,0.05,100,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values recursively:

```
y0list<-NULL  ##only do this once to initialize the lists. If this is running
y1list<-NULL  ## inside a function, make sure the environment is correct.
y2list<-NULL  ## if concerned, you should be ok if you initialize in the global env.
y3list<-NULL  

model <- function(t,x,params){

  y0 <- x[1]
  y0list<<-c(y0list, y0)

  y1 <- x[2]
  y1list<<-c(y1list, y1)

  y2 <- x[3]
  y2list<<-c(y2list, y2)

  y3 <- x[4]
  y3list<<-c(y3list, y3)

  ry <- params[1]
  mu <- params[2]
  d0 <- params[3]
  ay <- params[4]
  d1 <- params[5]
  by <- params[6]
  d2 <- params[7]
  cy <- params[8]
  d3 <- params[9]



  m <- rep(0,4)
  m[1] = ((ry*(1-mu)) - d0) * y0 #####I want to store the value of y0
  m[2] = (ay * y0) - (d1 * y1) #######and y1
  m[3] = (by * y1) - (d2 * y2) #######and y2
  m[4] = (cy * y2) - (d3 * y3) #######and y3, for each time ode23 calls my function

  return(m)

}
```

Check this example:

```
y0list<-NULL #outside the function
y1list<-NULL

foo.func<-function(data){
      sums<-NULL
      for(i in 1:length(data)){
        y0<-data[i]
        y0list<<-c(y0list, y0)

        y1<-data[sample(1:length(data),1)]
        y1list<<-c(y1list, y1)

        sums[i]<-y0+y1
      }
      return(sum(sums))
}

foo.func(1:10)
[1] 108

y0list
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

y1list
[1]  7  8  1  6  4  1  3 10  6  7
```

Be careful with these, as I suspect it will slow the function down, especially if it is being iterated many times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated your output `x`?

There are your variables `y0`, `y1`, `y2` and `y3` already stored!

You can load them via `x$y`.

```
head(x$y)
           y0       y1       y2       y3
[1,] 250000.0 500000.0 133333.3 13333333
[2,] 258578.2 500452.2 133347.0 13333333
[3,] 262670.0 500968.3 133372.2 13338593
[4,] 266889.3 501688.2 133418.4 13334541
[5,] 270474.3 502441.9 133476.5 13352665
[6,] 274911.7 503545.7 133574.8 13334574
```